# nvmw use command is not working

Tags: node.js, nvm

I used the command **nvmw ls** which lists the following versions

- system version (v0.12.6)
- v0.10.33

Then I used the command **nvmw use v0.10.33** to use the verion 0.10.33.

Then used the command **nvmw ls** to see the version being used, but I see the same version v0.12.6 running.

The output is below in the picture:

[image]

I use NVMW windows version. I ran the command in the directory where I have the source code which is a GIT repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from their [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvmw#notes) that nvmw does not work in windows powershell. It works in a windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to switch to command prompt just to use nvmw, you can always just type `cmd` in git bash and it will switch over into a command prompt and you can call `nvmw` normally.